# search and remove span tag inside table

Tags: jquery

I have the following code and want use jquery to search and remove the entire `<span>....</span>` tag inside the table.

Can anyone help, please?

```
<table class="display groceryCrudTable dataTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
    <tr>
        <td>24.80</td>
        <td><span id="func_date_temp" style="visibility:hidden;display:none;">2015-05-02</span>02/05/2015</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

UPDATE:
Sorry, I want to remove the span tag when a button is clicked.My button code is as following.The id and class for all the tags are dynamic, possibly will change everytime page is loaded.Only the Export wording is fixed/permenant:

```
<div class="DTTT_container ui-buttonset ui-buttonset-multi">
<a id="ToolTables_528e10207a9eb_0" class="DTTT_button ui-button ui-state-default DTTT_button_xls">
<span>Export</span>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 49px; height: 26px; z-index: 99;">
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has an ID, which is unique and can be targeted, then just use `remove()` :

```
$('#func_date_temp').remove();
```

to remove the textnode following the span as well (if that's what you're trying to do) :

```
$('#func_date_temp').parent().empty();
```

**EDIT:**

to do it on button click:

```
$('#ToolTables_528e10207a9eb_0').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#func_date_temp').remove();
});
```

Comment: Hi adenoe, this one is close to what i want.Can I do this? $('[id^="ToolTables_"] > span.html("Export")').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#func_date_temp').remove();
});

Comment: Nope, but you can do `$('[id^="ToolTables_"] > span:contains(Export)').on('click', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); $('#func_date_temp').remove(); });`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('table.display.groceryCrudTable').filter('span').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#func_date_temp').remove();
```

As `<span id="func_date_temp"` has `id`

---

References

[.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

[# id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

---

if you want to remove all `spans`

```
$('table.display.groceryCrudTable span').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

`remove()` removes entire element.

Try:

```
$(".dataTable").find("#func_date_temp").remove();
```